# cURL не записывается результат

Tags: php, curl, ftp

Использую данный код

```
$curl = curl_init();
$file = fopen("test.csv", 'wb');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://ftp.url.com/Inventory.csv"); #input
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file); #output
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
fclose($file);
```

`$file` — создается, скрипт работает, похоже что скачивает, но результат не записывает права на запись есть.
Попробовал закинуть на локальный сервер идентичный код, все записывает.
В обоих случаях скрипт заканчивает работу без ошибок.

добавил: 
Cоединение падает в time out. Почему на локальном сервере не уходит в time out, а на внешнем уходит.
стоит

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

зы:Через браузер подключается нормально, через FileZila тоже без проблем.
пробовал несколько фтп. Все так же на локальном ок, на сервере time out.

Comment: после curl_exec($curl); вставьте 
if(curl_exec($curl) === false)
{
    echo 'Ошибка curl: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
else
{
    echo 'Операция завершена без каких-либо ошибок';
}
и покажите результат

Comment: @madfan41k да , это прояснило ситуацию. Failed to connect to ftp.url.com port 21. Осталось выяснить почему на локальном сервере все хорошо, а на внешнем нет.

Comment: Вот здесь (http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1187) четко написано как сделать запросы на `cURL` .

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan скрипт рабочий. Наверно что-то не так с сервером. Но что именно не понимаю(

Comment: Ответ же дали вам, вы делаете `curl_exec(...)` и не записываете не где ответ.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan ответ записываться здесь "curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file); #output"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте указать переменную в которую поступает результат curl_exec():

```
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

В переменной $result будут содержаться данные, полученные через cURL, их уже можно записывать в файл.